# Dynamic memory allocation of two structs, struct A has a pointer to struct B

Tags: c

I have two structs A and B. Struct B has pointer in it of the type struct A.
Both structs/instances should allocate memory on runtime. The are linear dependent. I posted code which should present my idea, which doesn´t work. Please show me the right way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //EXIT_SUCCESS, calloc

struct A
{
 char *name;
 int id;
};

struct B
{
 char *buildingName;
 struct a *ptra;
};


int main()
{

   int employe = 1;
   int NrOfBuildinTemplates = 3;

   struct A *humans;
   struct B *buildings; 

   humans =  calloc(employe, sizeof(struct A));
   buildings = calloc(NrOfBuildinTemplates, sizeof(struct B));

   buildings[0].buildingName = strdup("Building A");
   buildings[1].buildingName = strdup("Building B");
   buildings[2].buildingName = strdup("Building C");


   int count = 100, n = 0;
   for (size_t i = 3; i < count; i++)
   {
      buildings = realloc (buildings, sizeof(struct B) * (i+1));
      buildings[i].buildingName = strdup("Building XYZ");
      buildings[i].ptra = &(humans[n]);
      buildings[i].ptra->name = strdup("NameXYZ"); 
      humans = realloc(humans, sizeof(struct A) * (n+1));
      n++;
   }


   for (size_t i = 3; i < count; i++)
   {
      printf("%s -> %s\n", buildings[i].buildingName, buildings[i].ptra->name);
      n++;
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description. Are you getting compile-time errors? Or runtime errors? Or warnings? Does your code not behave the way you want it to? Please elaborate. BTW, what is this line trying to do? `(*buildings->ptra) calloc(1, buildings->ptra)`. Are you trying to cast the return value of `calloc` to... what?

Comment: Create functions for creating pointers and allocating memory, then you can call something like `humans = createNewHumans()`. So it's all encapsulated and you can isolate creation code that you can debug and use more easily.

Comment: With this code I get a compile-time error. I created the code to present my idea how I think to have to allocate dynamic memory for two structs who one points to the other.

Comment: `struct A` is not `struct a`. This is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
  buildings = realloc(buildings, i+1);
```

This is wrong. It should be:

```
  buildings = realloc(buildings, sizeof(struct B) * (i+1));
```

There's a similar issue with this:

```
  humans = realloc(humans, n+1);
```

Also, this code is completely baffling. I can't suggest how to fix it because I have no idea what you think it does:

```
  buildings[i].ptra = (*buildings->ptra) calloc(1, buildings->ptra);
  buildings[i].ptra = &(humans[n]);
  buildings[i].ptra = strdup("NameXYZ");
```

Comment: It should allocate space for the pointer ptra. And than buildings[i].ptra should hold the address to humans[n]. And the last line should be  buildings[i].ptra->name = strdup("NameXYZ"); I correct it to in my post.

Comment: @ChrieJ The pointer is part of `buildings[i]`, which has already been allocated. The first line makes no sense.

Comment: I removed it from the post